# (Tk) How to give focus to input

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

I want to make a input box with python3. And use following code. Here is a problem. After run the code, the input box appeared. And I must click the box and then enter something. What can I do if I want to enter something without click first?

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

Label(master,text="enter sth here").grid(row=0)

e = Entry(master)

e.grid(row=0,column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=0, column=10, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `focus_set()` on your `Entry` instance:

```
e = Entry(master)

e.grid(row=0,column=1)
e.focus_set()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I not only learned how to solve it but also learned how to describe the problem in English(much important)....LoL